# В чем различие AbsolutePanel и VerticalPanel?

Tags: gwt

В чем существенное различие этих компонентов?

Я выбираю `absoрlutePanel`, т.к. решает задачу добавления элементов друг под другом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbsolutePanel` - виджет, основанный на `div`-элементе c возможностью указания координат виджетов-детей.

`VerticalPanel` основан на таблице и каждый новый виджет внутри него помещается в отдельный ряд (<tr>).

На `AbsolutePanel` друг под друга добавляться будут только блочные элементы, а в `VerticalPanel` - любые.

Если внутри панели вы будете использовать только блочные элементы и вам не нужны ни возможности таблицы, ни абсолютное позиционирование, рекомендую использовать `FlowPanel` - самую простую реализацию панели с несколькими виджетами.